# Buildozer: Error compiling Cython file

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

Can't to compile APK. And I don't understand why thr error is occure. Another applications can be compiled without errors. I have tried to change Cython versions - useless.

It is my Buildozer.spec

```
[app]

p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Title of your application
title = Trade_SQL_v2

# (str) Package name
package.name = trade_prog_SQL

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.trade

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas, pyo

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin, fotos

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
#version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)'['"]
#version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
version = 2.0

# (list) Application requirements
requirements = kivy, sqlite3, hostpython2

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements = xcamera

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = /home/sergen/monkey.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = /home/sergen/Картинки/Lime.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1


#
# Android specific
#

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES, CAMERA,  EXPAND_STATUS_BAR

# (int) Android API to use
android.api = 17

# (int) Minimum API required (8 = Android 2.2 devices)
#android.minapi = 14

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 22

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = False

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.ndk_path = /home/sergen/Android/android-ndk-r9c

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
android.sdk_path = /home/sergen/android-studio/sdk

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
android.p4a_dir = /home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# List as sections
#
# You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
# Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
# Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
# Instead of doing:
#
#     [app]
#     source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
# This can be translated into:
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns]
#     license
#     data/audio/*.wav
#     data/images/original/*
#


# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Profiles
#
# You can extend section / key with a profile
# For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
# HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
# and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#     [app@demo]
#     title = My Application (demo)
#
#     [app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#     images/hd/*
#
# Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#     buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

It is part of log from Terminal:

```
/python-for-android-master/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/threads ...
Compiling /home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/threads/Py25Queue.py ...
Compiling /home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/threads/__init__.py ...
Compiling /home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pygame/version.py ...
PYTHONPATH=/home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python-install/lib/python2.7 LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python/Python-2.7.2::/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib \
    /home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python/Python-2.7.2/hostpython -Wi -t -c "import lib2to3.pygram, lib2to3.patcomp;lib2to3.patcomp.PatternCompiler()"
Leaving ARM enviromnent
Skipped build_sdl
Skipped build_pygame
Skipped build_pyjnius
Call build_android
Entering in ARM enviromnent
Compiler found at /home/sergen/Android/android-ndk-r9c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin//arm-linux-androideabi-gcc

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# Android-specific python services.

include "config.pxi"
^
------------------------------------------------------------

android/_android.pyx:3:0: 'config.pxi' not found

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
# Android-specific python services.

include "config.pxi"

IF BOOTSTRAP == 'pygame':
            ^
------------------------------------------------------------

android/_android.pyx:5:13: Compile-time name 'BOOTSTRAP' not defined

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
            rctx.top = 0
            self.height = mActivity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight() - (rctx.bottom - rctx.top)
            # print('final height: {0}'.format(self.height))

    ll = LayoutListener()
    IF BOOTSTRAP == 'sdl2':
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

android/_android.pyx:200:17: Compile-time name 'BOOTSTRAP' not defined

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    binfo.MODEL = BUILD_MODEL
    binfo.PRODUCT = BUILD_PRODUCT
    binfo.VERSION_RELEASE = BUILD_VERSION_RELEASE
    return binfo

IF IS_PYGAME:
           ^
------------------------------------------------------------

android/_android.pyx:285:12: Compile-time name 'IS_PYGAME' not defined

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 9, in <module>
    sdl_libs = lib_dict[os.environ['BOOTSTRAP']]
  File "/home/sergen/Android/python-for-android-master/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'BOOTSTRAP'
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy sqlite3 hostpython2" -d "trade_prog_SQL"
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```